# handling session variables inside http.request in express

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

Hi.                                                                              When i print the req.session.mySessValue in UI , the value is empty. I think the assigning of req.session.mySessValue = dt.myValue; (express-session) is not proper. could anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance.my express code is

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        if(!req.xx) {
        return res.redirect('/firstView');  
        }
    var options = {
           .......
        };
        var call = http.request(options, function(resp) {
            resp.on('data', function(dt) {            
                var jsondata = JSON.parse(dt);          
                req.session.mySessValue = dt.myValue;
            });
        });
        call.end();
        call.on('error', function(e) {       
           console.log("error" +e.message)
        });

        var v = {
            title: 'sample',
            req : req       
        }
        res.render('myview', v);

    });
```

Comment: Are you sure `dt.myValue` has value? and have you tried `call.on('data', ...)` instead of `resp.on('data', ...)` just like you did with `call.on('error`, ...)`?

Comment: And also you can try this: 
https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessionsave
and see if there is an error coming back

Comment: @mkinawy - i am sure that i get the required response and dt.myValue has value.

Comment: have you tried logging the value of req.session.mySessValue somewhere (or even posting it in an alert) right after you assign it, to confirm whether or not it is assigning correctly?

Comment: Are you using Redis or any other third party Session storage?

Comment: Thanks mkinawy for all your reply, sorry i am new to this concept. i am not aware of Redis. I have just installed and set express-session configuration. I am sure there is no issue with that. Actually i have printed the req.session.mySessValue value right after the line req.session.mySessValue = dt.myValue; i am able to see the value in console,but in UI the value is not getting printed. I have set another session variable outside the call , but that value is getting printed in UI

Comment: @mkinawy - really thanks a lot for your time.i think when i have placed the res.render('myview',v) inside the call like var call = http.request(options, function(resp) {
            resp.on('data', function(dt) {            
                var jsondata = JSON.parse(dt);          
                req.session.mySessValue = dt.myValue;    var v = {
            title: 'sample',
            req : req       
        }
        res.render('myview', v);
            });
        }); I am getting the session value in UI. Thanks again mkinawy